# How to find which function became from "from - import" module

Tags: python, import, module, libraries, python-importlib

I have question regarding to "from - import" function. For ex. I have 3 files: one.py, two.py, three.py.

Content of three.py file:

```
from one import *
from two import *


variable1
variable2

def func1()

def func2()

def func3()
```

Let's say, I don't have a permission to above two files and I can't open them. My question is, how to check which function and which variable become from one.py or two.py file? Is there any command or something like that?

Comment: have u checked `dir(one)`  incase you use `import one`. If you are using `from one import *`, then just use `dir()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getfile` from the `inspect` module

```
Return the name of the (text or binary) file in which an object was defined. This will fail with a TypeError if the object is a built-in module, class, or function.
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile

Answer (score 1):

```
print(func1.__module__)
print(func2.__module__)
print(func3.__module__)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could apply a try-except to the import statement.

```py
try:
  from one import *
  from two import *
except ImportError:
  # Override variables after failed import
  var1 = ...
  var2 = ...
```

Answer (score 0):

you can call the function\variable with the namespace of the module

and cheak with try/ except  that you don't heave error when you importing  the modules

```
   try:
       from one
       one.foo()
       one.variable1

   except ImportError as exception:
       print(exception)

   try:
       from two
       two.foo()
       two.variable1

   except ImportError as exception:
       print(exception)
```